# enviar valor de attr por $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `link a`, que se clicado, leva a um **scrpt** **ajax** para deleção do **ID**.

Com o `código` abaixo não consigo pegar o `id` na **página** do **php**

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("a.bloqDesbloq").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "../_requeridos/bloqueiaAdministrador.php",
            type: 'POST',            
            data : {
                    'idadministrador'   : $(this).attr('idadmin'),
                    'bloq'              : $(this).attr('bloq')
                   },
            beforeSend: function() {
            },
            success: function (retorno) {

                if (retorno == "OK") {

                    alert('Bloqueado com sucesso');
                    location.reload();

                } else {

                    alert("Erro na bloqueio");

                }

            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

          return false;

  });

});
```

o $`_post` chega no **php** array vazio.

Onde estou errando?

Obs.: Se eu fizer

```
alert( $(this).attr('idadmin'))
```

Antes de chamar o `ajax`, os valores aparecem

Comment: Os dados que serão enviados ao PHP deverão ficar em `data`. Tente fazer algo como `data: {idadministrador: ...}`

Comment: fiz isso, mas dá indefinido no php. post e get chegam no php com Array ( ) Array ( ). Ou seja, arrays vazios

Comment: como está o código antes de chamar o ajax? talvez o seu "$(this)" não represente mais o campo que você deseja puxar as informações.

Comment: antes do ajax não tem nada. Mas como dito na pergunta, se eu der um alert em $(this).attr('idadmin') antes do ajax, o valor sai normal

Comment: adicionei a pergunta todo o js para ficar mais clara

Comment: Coloque o conteúdo do seu `a.bloqDesbloq`, quero entender porque você está pegando um atributo `idadmin` e outro `bloq` da mesma `tag <a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testei aqui o seu código atual, ele realmente não passa nada para o PHP, mas aí retirei as últimas duas linhas do ajax e funcionou:

```
},
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false
});
```

para

```
},
cache: false
});
```

(Lembre-se de tirar a virgula depois de cache também)

Creio que algum destes valores impedia de enviar o post corretamente. Vou pesquisar melhor para saber o que eles fazem e logo mais edito a minha resposta.

-Edit:

Pelo que vi em http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ usando contentType: false; irá forçar a enviar os dados sem um "tipo de conteúdo". este valor você pode remover, para que o ajax use o padrão dele.

Ao usar o processData: false você diz ao ajax para não "organizar" seu objeto como STRING, mas o "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (Padrão ajax) precisa ser passado como STRING. O Padrão desta opção também é true, então você pode eliminar esta linha.

o "cache: false" não causou erros no seu código.

Comment: obrigado, era exatamente isso. Programando e aprendendo!